# How to grep contents in HEX specifying the pattern in decimals?

Tags: grep, ack

I have a file with the following contents (as a text file in UTF-8)

```
e04ba1af81d887979ddcee1dc23f2531
43f85926fdb6a668386ee354f8b836a1
b53614f5139c052ec08ea1ecd2532daf
e9b3914d7b1e1bf8e6feab621330245b
bbcad02116316176385fbfb294ee77b4
```

I need to ensure that this file contains a number `46390` (decimal). It equals `b536` in HEX that is the beginning of the 3rd line.

How do I use `grep` or `awk` to make it convert both file and pattern to binary representation and then do a search?  In other words, make searching base independent considering that bases are known.

Sample output:

1)

```
$ cat file.txt | grep 46390
```

**1011010100110110**1010011110101000100111001110000000101001011101100000010001110101000011110110011010010010100110010110110101111
(it's **b536**14f5139c052ec08ea1ecd2532daf in hex)

2) A file contains a single string `3CA547A` (binary `0011110010100101010001111010`).
I am given a decimal representation of some sequence. The file may contain this sequence and it may be not aligned by 8 bits. Let's assume this sequence is equal to decimal 15 (binary `1111`)

The command:

```
$ cat file.text | grep 15
```

The result would contain 2 occurrences:

00**1111**001010010101000**1111**010

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: each of the 5 numbers in your example are very much larger than 46390

Comment: Does the file start with the four characters `e`, `0`, `4`, `b`, or is what you've written here a hex representation of binary data?

Comment: @roaima It does start with these characters. It's not a binary data

Comment: Then why are you showing it as binary data? This question really doesn't make any sense whatsoever

Comment: @roaima Because the file contains hex as a text. It really doesn't matter where is this data from. I have to deal with such a representation.

Comment: I'm not fussed about the source of your data; as you say, that's what you've got to work with, and as a concept that's fine. I'm trying to understand what on earth it is you want to achieve.

Comment: The closest I can get is that you've a series of newline-separated bitstreams, each represented by hex digits (4 bits each), and you want to find which of these bitstreams contains a matching binary sequence. Except that the sequence is given to you as decimal.

Comment: If that really is the case then IMO the easiest way of handling this would be to convert everything to textual binary (strings of 1s and 0s) and just grep. You'd need to specify MSB-first or LSB-first in each case, I suspect, as otherwise you'd quite probably end up having architecture-dependent code.

Comment: @roaima Well, yeah. You clarified the problem and I didn't manage to.

Comment: Have I? Please feel free to take anything of mine here that helps people understand what you're asking.

Comment: A solution depends on what the file is. From the context given it seems to be a series of big endian 16-bit values. Correct?

Answer (score 3):

How about simply using `printf` to do the conversion?

```
printf '^%x\n' 46390 | grep -f- file
```

(I don't see hoe converting both to binary would help)

Comment: or `printf '^%x\n' 46390 | grep -f- <(sed -n 3p file)`, or `awk -v search="$(printf '^%x\n' 46390)" 'NR==3 && $0 ~ search' file` to match on only the 3rd line.

Comment: hmmm....reading the Q again, I'm not sure if that's actually part of the OP's criteria. I thought it was, at first....but OP might be just pointing out where the value is in the sample input.

Comment: The problem here is that the binary sequence may be shifted by a non-multiple of 8. So I assume the file contents should be transformed to make the search bitwise.